# Strange double answer cname in dig

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dig

I want to host a web site with github.io, using www.nv-gr.fr

I have put an `A` on `@` and another on `www`

My zone is :

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1531775542 10800 3600 604800 10800
@ 1800 IN A 185.199.108.153
@ 1800 IN A 185.199.109.153
@ 1800 IN A 185.199.110.153
@ 1800 IN A 185.199.111.153
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
blog 10800 IN CNAME blogs.vip.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME webmail.gandi.net.
www 1800 IN A 185.199.108.153
```

Making dig www.nv-gr.fr, I get:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.nv-gr.fr.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.nv-gr.fr.       8757    IN  CNAME   nv-gr.fr.nv-gr.fr.
```

Why do I have this strange `nv-gr.fr.nv-gr.fr.`

Comment: I don't see any such record. Wait three hours and try again.

Comment: I could go to sleep and wake up happy. Thank for the check, but it's probably because I played with it.